# ng-click does not work in AngularJS custom directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I created a directive, everything is working well except that "ng-click" does not work from my controller. Nothing happens when i click the button. What am I getting wrong?

Here is my app.js

```
var app = angular.module('mainApp',[ 'ui.router' ]);

app.config(['$stateProvider', function($stateProvider) {
  $stateProvider
        .state('login', {
            url: '/login',
            controller: 'LoginPageCtrl',
        });
}])

app.directive('loginPage', function loginPage() {
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        templateUrl: 'app/partial/login.html',
    }
})

app.controller('LoginPageCtrl', function($scope) {

    $scope.login = function() {
        alert("You Clicked Me")
    }

})
```

Then in my login.html I have

```
<button ng-click="login()" type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Sign in</button>
```

EDITED -- JUST ADDED CODES BELOW

Am using directive because of the login am using to use specific css for different page layout (login page & user page). It might sound awkward though.

Here is my index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="BlurAdmin">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Admin</title>


<link ng-if="!$authPage" rel="stylesheet" href="styles/app-b6796b3788.css">

<link ng-if="$authPage"  rel="stylesheet" href="styles/auth-a200a050c1.css">

</head>
<body>

<page-content ng-if="!$authPage"></page-content>

<login-page ng-if="$authPage"></login-page>


<script src="scripts/app-5a80256787.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think `templateUrl: 'app/partial/login.html'` should be in your $stateProvider for the login state

Comment: No, I dont want it to load from the main index, putting it in the login state will load the page normal, But I am using directive so a fit in my login of using a custom css and page layout for the login page

Comment: it might depend on the version, but you can't have a controller without a template

Comment: I just edited the question and added my index.html

Comment: where is the `ui-view` on your page?

Comment: Ohh... I omitted that. And I just added it now, and it worked fine. I will post it as an answer. Thanks for the clue

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved by adding `<div ui-view></div>` which was ommited. Now I can now call the `templateUrl` in the login `state` to load in the `ui-view`

Here is the new layout.html

```
    <div ui-view></div>
```

Then the directive now changed in the app.js

```
app.config(['$stateProvider', function($stateProvider) {
  $stateProvider
    .state('login', {
        url: '/login',
        controller: 'LoginPageCtrl',
        templateUrl: 'app/pages/login.form.html',

    });
}])

app.directive('loginPage', function loginPage() {
   return {
      restrict: 'EA',
      templateUrl: 'app/partial/layout.html',
    }
 })
```